# PostgreSQL NULL vs Separate Table

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

I have an ever-growing table called `transactions` which grows ~10 million rows per month.

This table has a `jsonb` column called `extra`.

70% of `extra` column of the `transactions` records are NULL and the rest of them has a json value like so:

```
{
   "lang": "en",
   "pages": 3,
   "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi. Arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis. Morbi tristique senectus et netus. Mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin. Sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum..."
}
```

*Notice: All `extra` json keys are fixed for all rows and will not change.*

An overview of `transactions` table :

```
id |  price  | type |    extra    
-------------------------------------------
 1 | 2000.00 | SMS  |     null    
 2 | 2000.00 | SMS  |     null    
 3 | 4000.00 | SMS  |     null    
 4 | 5000.00 | SMS  | {"lang": "en", "pages":8, "message":"Lore..."}
 5 | 4000.00 | SMS  |     null    
 6 | 4000.00 | SMS  |     null    
 7 | 5000.00 | SMS  | {"lang": "de", "pages":5, "message":"Some..."}
```

**Why I did that?**

I'm using `jsonb` column instead of three separate columns to avoid many NULL values.

With `jsonb` I only have 30% NULLs only on 1 column, But when I use 3 separate columns instead of 1 jsonb column I have 30% NULL for each column.

**The Question:**

Is it good idea to split the my `extra` column into 3 separate columns?

Like so:

```
id |  price  | type | lang  | pages |  message       
--------------------------------------------
 1 | 2000.00 | SMS  |  null |  null | null
 2 | 2000.00 | SMS  |  null |  null | null
 3 | 4000.00 | SMS  |  null |  null | null
 4 | 5000.00 | SMS  |  en   |   8   | Lorem...
 5 | 4000.00 | SMS  |  null |  null | null
 6 | 4000.00 | SMS  |  null |  null | null
 7 | 5000.00 | SMS  |  de   |   5   | Some...
```

Or instead, I can add an extra table(for example `transaction_info`) with One-To-One relationship. Like so:

**transcations**

```
id |  price  | type
-------------------
 1 | 2000.00 | SMS 
 2 | 2000.00 | SMS 
 3 | 4000.00 | SMS 
 4 | 5000.00 | SMS 
 5 | 4000.00 | SMS 
 6 | 4000.00 | SMS 
 7 | 5000.00 | SMS
```

**transaction_info**

```
id |  transaction_id  | lang  | pages |  message       
--------------------------------------------
 1 |       4          |   en  |   8   |  Lorem...
 2 |       7          |   de  |   5   |  Some...
```

With this approach I don't have any NULL values on both tables.

Which one do you prefer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to read some about normal forms - 1. NF says - every value is atomic. That expects so any attribute has own column - it is usually good idea (when number of attributes are less than 50). NULL value needs only 1bite - and probably storing data in clean relational 1NF is more effective than in JSON format.

So, because your new columns are only three, then my reply to your question is yes. It is good idea.

The second question one or two tables - there is not clean reply - both variants are correct from relation model perspective. If there is visible separation in reality - there are two entities, then I prefer two tables. Elsewhere (and when number of columns is small) I prefer one table.

Comment: I did, I prefer one table in this case. Only when the probability of extra info is low, then two tables has some benefit.